# Create multiple horizontal scrolling layouts within a scroll view

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, horizontalscrollview

So I have a Scroll View which contains a relative layout. I want that relative layout to have 3 or more layouts that can be scrolled. I know how to implement that with HorizontalScrollView, but before execution, I have no idea how many elements the HorizontalScrollView is going to have. Should I use ViewPager for this? What I would like the most is a HorizontalListView.

Would you recommend something like this:
https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView

Or should I add views programmatically in a HorizontalScrollView?

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView is widget that should be used to keep static layouts inside. In general - ones that just are ~slightly bigger that the screen.

If you need something really dynamic you should use elements based on adapters like ListView, or ViewPager.